How do I access my Minecraft Server's console after launching the server on Ubuntu Server?
I used this guide to create and launch a Minecraft server using Ubuntu Server on an old computer of mine. The server is running, but I don't know how to access the Minecraft server console. It still just has me in the default terminal. I've gathered that I probably have to use Screen, but I'm not sure how. I'm really new to this, so any help is appreciated.

Your minecraft's systemd config file is already configured to work with Screen.
To connect to the session, you first need to know the session name.
Start by searching for it with screen -list:
root@instance:/home/ubuntu# screen -list
There is a screen on:
        3843276.mc-1    (10/13/24 13:36:35)     (Detached)
1 Socket in /run/screen/S-root.

In my case, the ID of my Screen session is 3843276.
I can connect to it by using screen -r 3843276.
To detach from a screen session after you've connected, press CTRL + A, then press D.
